# module Error using InterX function translated to python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to use the function InterX which finds the intersection of two curves, but I am having always the same error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. No matter the kind of data I introduce into the function.

The function can be found in https://github.com/kelseynlucas/InterX.git

In the description of the function the author says: 
InterX Intersection of curves

Input:
   -L1x - Pandas dataframe of x-values for curve 1
   -L1y - Pandas dataframe of y-values for curve 1
Optional input:
   -L2x - Pandas dataframe of x-values for curve 2
   -L2y - Pandas dataframe of y-values for curve 2
So I have created a dataframe for the x and y values of the straight line called "Line" and another for the curve called "Curve" and used the function.

However even if I introduce the DataFrame, or the arrays or the data manually to the function I always having the same error.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import InterX

x_t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, True)
z_t = np.array((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.055, 0.41, 1.23, 4))
X_P = np.array((2,4))
Z_P = np.array((3,-1))

Line = pd.DataFrame(np.array((X_P,Z_P)))
Curve = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x_t,z_t]))
Curve = Curve.T
P = InterX(Line[0],Line[1],Curve[0],Curve[1])
```

I expect the ouput P = [3.5 , 0]. However I am having always the same error:

line 22, in 
    P = InterX(x_t,z_t,X_P,Z_P)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the module name and the function inside have the same name and when you write `P = InterX(...` you call the module, not the function in it, which leads to the error.

Use:

```
from InterX import InterX
...
P = InterX(Line[0],Line[1],Curve[0],Curve[1])
```

or

```
import InterX
...
P = InterX.InterX(Line[0],Line[1],Curve[0],Curve[1])
```

or

```
import InterX as interX
...
P = interX.InterX(Line[0],Line[1],Curve[0],Curve[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I have implemented your suggestions and the code do not present any errors. However the fucntion is not working properly. `import numpy as np;
from InterX import InterX;
import pandas as pd;
L1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,-1],[4,4]]));
L2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,4],[4,-1]]));
P = InterX(L1[0],L1[1],L2[0],L2[1])` the expected results is P = [3,1.5]  but the function returns = [none, none]

Comment: Thanks, indeed the answer you gave was good. However, I do not have the reputation point enough to vote answers :( Thank you I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have done the new question. It would be nice if you can vote up to the questions. Thank you very much for your help