# Malfunction of the translated code InterX to python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I want to use the function InterX to find the intersection of two curves. However the function does not return the expected result. The function is availabel [here](https://github.com/kelseynlucas/InterX)

The function always return the point of intersection as P =  None, None. When a valid point was expected.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from InterX import InterX

x_t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, True)
z_t = np.array((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.055, 0.41, 1.23, 4))
X_P = np.array((2,4))
Z_P = np.array((3,-1))

Line = pd.DataFrame(np.array((X_P,Z_P)))
Curve = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x_t,z_t]))
Curve = Curve.T
P = InterX(Line[0],Line[1],Curve[0],Curve[1])
```

In this script the expected result was P = [3.5,0]. However, the resulting point P is P = [None,None]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - use:

```
P = InterX(L1, L1, L2, L2)
```

or

```
P = InterX(L1.iloc[:,0].to_frame(),L1.iloc[:,1].to_frame(),L2.iloc[:,0].to_frame(),L2.iloc[:,1].to_frame())
```

For a detailed answer see the following that refers to the code of your original question.

**This refers to the code of the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080389/module-error-using-interx-function-translated-to-python):**

You need two pass two dataframes with x and y values (it would be of course much more logical if InterX would accept 4 Series or 2 DataFrames respectively).
InterX then gets the x and y values in a very convoluted way from these dataframes in lines 90 through 119 (which could be done far more easyly). So the working solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from InterX import InterX

x_t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, True)
z_t = np.array((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.055, 0.41, 1.23, 4))
x_P = np.array((2,4))
z_P = np.array((3,-1))

curve_x = pd.DataFrame(x_t)
curve_z = pd.DataFrame(z_t)
line_x = pd.DataFrame(X_P)
line_z = pd.DataFrame(Z_P)
p = InterX(line_x, line_z, curve_x, curve_z)
```

Output of print(p):

```
    xs   ys
0  3.5  0.0
```

Please note that according to the [python naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) (PEP8) function and variable names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores.

---

I find the code of InterX very difficult to understand, a much cleaner solution (along with a nice plot) is [this one](https://github.com/sukhbinder/intersection).
With

```
x_t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10, True)
z_t = np.array((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.055, 0.41, 1.23, 4))
X_P = np.array((2,4))
Z_P = np.array((3,-1))

x,y = intersection(x_t,z_t,X_P,Z_P)
print(x,y)
plt.plot(x_t,z_t,c='r')
plt.plot(X_P,Z_P,c='g')
plt.plot(x,y,'*k')
plt.show()
```

we get `[3.5] [-0.]` and this picture:

[image]

Comment: I edited your question to insert the code from the original question, because its easier to understand with different sized dataframes. It will become visible to you as soon it is reviewed. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It has been tremendously usefull and also you have taught new stuff of programing. Thanks a lot!